# Input (button) check and uncheck event (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input, checkbox

I need to do different things depending on whether a checkbox with an ID attribute is checked or unchecked by a mouse. An event needs to be fired when either a check or an uncheck is performed. I suppose one could use a single check event handler and just see what the check state is but I don't know how.

Comment: have you heard about the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) event, if so try to use a [change event handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the change event which will be fired when the checkbox state is changed, so register a change event handler using the id of the checkbox

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    //change event handler
    $('#myid').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            //checked do something
            $('span').text('checked');
        } else {
            //unchecked do something else
            $('span').text('unchecked');
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9RKDQ/)

- [Document Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change)
- [change event handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector)

Probably you should start with

- [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [Learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_preconf() { 
    if(document.getElementById("step1_full").checked) { 
        $( "#step2_half" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $( "#step3_half" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $( "#step4_half" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $( "#step5_half" ).prop( "disabled", true );

    } 
}
```